# How to pass a parameter to Salesforce Lightning JavaScript controller method

Tags: javascript, javascript-controller

I would like to pass a parameter to a JavaScript controller method so the method could format the data...

**Component**

```
<ul>
   <aura:iteration items="{!v.listOfStuff}" var="a">
      <li>{! c.formatFromUntil(a.Start__c, a.End__c) }</li>
   </aura:iteration>
<ul/>
```

**JavaScript Controller**

```
formatFromUntil : function(starts, ends){
   // format the two date like below
   return 'from 3:00 PM until 4:30 PM'
},
```

But the developer console will not save, and I get this error:

> Failed to save exampleComponent.cmp: unexpected token: '(' at column X of experssion: c.formatFromUntil(a.Start__c, a.End__c) : Source

It obviously does not want me accessing controller methods like this.

How should I be approaching this?

Comment: 1.No you can't pass parameters through markup, you can do it by creating child component , in that cmp you want to create a attribute and set dateformat value , via doinit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to calculate the data in your controller/helper:

```
listOfStuff.forEach(item => 
    item.FromUntil = helper.formatFromUtil(item.Start__c, item.End__c);
```

Which you then render normally:

```
  <li>{!a.FromUntil }</li>
```

If these are actual records that you intend to send back to the server later, you might want a "wrapper" instead:

```
listOfStuff = sourceList.map(function(item) 
    return { record: record, 
             FromUtil: helper.formatFromUntil(record.Start__c, record.End__c) 
});
```

You'd need to adjust your markup and any other code that relies on the item structure accordingly.

Comment: And if the ListOfStuff is a List<Account> it will add the FromUntil property?

Comment: @Robs You can put whatever you want in the list, but be careful if you're sending it back to the server, as it may have undesirable side effects.